# MSP430 SPI not working at higher speeds (4+ MHz)

Tags: spi, msp430

I'm trying to output a byte's waveform using SPI in master mode. This is working as expected when using the REFOCLK at 32 KHz. However, when using XT2 at 4 MHz or the DCOCLK (at 20 MHz) the waveforms look completely wrong, as shown in the attached picture. Why is this happening? Is their some special setting I need or is the MSP430F5529 just not capable of SPI at these speeds?

First image: Output at 4+ MHz (50 ns horizontal intervals), Second image: Output at 32 KHz

[image]
[image]

(Measured with the [Hantek HT6022BE](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009H4AYII), which has a bandwidth of 20 MHz.)

Clearly, the 4+ MHz is not putting out the correct waveform, while the 32 KHz is.

```
WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;                           // Stop watchdog timer

SetVcoreUp(0x01);                                   //Bring up power, taken directly from datasheet
SetVcoreUp(0x02);
SetVcoreUp(0x03);
__bis_SR_register(SCG0);                            //Disable FLL
P5SEL |= (BIT2 + BIT3);                             //Set crystal ports
UCSCTL6 &= ~XT2OFF;                                 //Enable XT2
UCSCTL3 |= SELREF_2;                                //Set FLL
UCSCTL4 |= SELA_2;                                  //Set ACLK also
UCSCTL6 |= XT2DRIVE_0;                              //Select power needed for XT2
do
{
    UCSCTL7 &= ~(XT2OFFG + XT1LFOFFG + DCOFFG);     //Clear fault flags
    SFRIFG1 &= ~OFIFG;                              //Clear general oscillator fault flag
}
while (SFRIFG1 & OFIFG);                            //If fault, OFIFG&SFRIFG1 will be non zero (true)

UCSCTL4 |= SELS__XT2CLK;

P1DIR |= (BIT0 + BIT2);
P2DIR |= BIT2;                                      //Set P2.2 as out direction to monitor clock
P2SEL |= BIT2;                                      //Select P2.2 as SMCLK output

__bic_SR_register(SCG0);                            //Enable FLL

UCB0CTL1 = UCSWRST;                                 //Put UCSI in reset state for configuration
UCB0CTL0 |= (UCSYNC + UCMST + UCMSB + UCCKPH);      //Enable settings: SPI mode (insetad of UART) + Master + Most sig byte
P3SEL |= BIT0;                                      //Port select
P3DIR |= BIT0;
UCB0CTL1 |= UCSSEL1;                                //Disable UCSI reset state and select SMCLK src
UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;                               //Enable UCSI

while (1)
{
    while (!(UCB0IFG & UCTXIFG));                   //Delay until UCB0TXBUF is empty

    UCB0TXBUF = 0xEE;                               //transmit 11101110
    __delay_cycles(10000);
}
```

p.s., I know the SPI is synchronous, but I need these high speeds because I'm actually just using it for the waveform, not to communicate with an SPI slave

Comment: What do you mean by "just using it for the wave form", if your just generating a waveform, then use the GPIO ports or a timer

Comment: @laptop2d its easier to get precise timing with the SPI peripheral on my microcontroller. I'm trying to control these: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812B.pdf

Comment: Show the time scale of the images, and specify exactly how you measured them.

Comment: I've never had any problems using any of the MSP430's clocking systems. In fact, they are shockingly capable and full-featured. They just work. (And I don't know of much that competes with the B7 timer peripheral, either.) I don't want to read your code and a datasheet right now. So I'm not adding an answer now. But I've no question the chip can do reasonable things for you. With a 32 kHz xtal available, I'd usually set up the DCO to continually lock the DCO to it with a PID loop. But that's application dependent.

Comment: @CL. the horizontal increments are 50 NS for the 4 Mhz img

Comment: @jonk yeah I agree. 4 MHz is pretty reasonable, so I'm probably doing something wrong.